# Can numba, multiprocessor and random number generators work together?

Tags: python, numba, random-seed, multiprocessor

I'm trying to get numba, multiprocessor and random number generators work together. I have downsized my real problem to the following piece of code containing the important elements. The following works for me.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import multiprocessing as mp
 
#@jit(nopython=True) 
def compute_with_random(j,rng):
  x=rng.normal(0,0.3,j)
  y=np.sum(x)/j
  return y

#@jit(nopython=True) 
def single(args):
  (n,se)=args
  rng = np.random.default_rng(se)
  s=0
  for i in range(1,n):
   s+=compute_with_random(i,rng)
  return s

def Call_Multi():
  seed_sequence = np.random.SeedSequence(12345)  
  seeds = seed_sequence.spawn(4)

  all_ins=[ (500,seeds[0]), (700,seeds[1]), (400,seeds[2]), (200,seeds[3]) ]
  pool = mp.Pool(4)
  result = pool.map( single, all_ins )  

  return result

if __name__=='__main__':
  print( Call_Multi() )
```

As for my real problem the two functions compute_with_random() and single() take quite long and numba can accelerate them I want to use the numba decorator, so using the @jit decorators above result in the following error.

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: [1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
[1m[1mnon-precise type pyobject[0m
[0m[1mDuring: typing of argument at C:\test\test_rng_numba.py (16)   [0m [1m
File "test_rng_numba.py", line 16:[0m
[1mdef single(args):
[1m (n,se)=args
[0m [1m^[0m[0m
This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
... (truncated)
```

If I replace x=rng.normal(0,0.3,j) by x=np.random.normal(0,0.3,j) and remove the arguments rng in compute_with_random() and se in single() the example works also fine with numba. So probably there is a problem with numba and the parallel random number generator, or the seeds/rng. The random number generator with rng.normal() is suppossed to make independent chains of random numbers for each process. Any ideas how to solve that issue? thanks

Comment: I think you could use the thread of Numba instead of multiprocessing. I do not know how Numba Jitted function are supposed to work with process forks yet but it can possibly cause weird errors.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use the thread stuff for my case? I've already tried parallel=True in the decorator and prange, which did not work for my real problem.

Comment: The main issue here is the control of the seed states. Numba does not like this as parameter because it is a CPython object type unsupported by Numba (and you cannot use such objects in nopython jitted functions anyway). More generally, the documentations state "Numba supports top-level functions from the numpy.random module, but *does not allow you to create individual RandomState instances*.". Thus, if you need to control the seed with Numba the same way, this is certainly not supported yet.